# Go - run embed script with arguments

Tags: python, go, embed

i'm developing a Go application, which should be able to run python scripts.  the scripts are located inside `scripts/python` folder, and i include them in the go binary using `//go:embed` annotation, and then run them using `exec.Command`, the following way:

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    _ "embed"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)    
//go:embed scripts/python/argsTest.py
var argsTestScript string
    
func main() {
   args:= []string{}
   runCommand(args, argsTestScript)
}
func runCommand(args []string, scriptFile string)  {
    c := exec.Command("python", args...)
    c.Stdin = strings.NewReader(scriptFile)
    output, err := c.Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error = ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("output = ", string(output))
}
```

when `argTest.py` simply prints the arguments -

```
import sys

print('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
print('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
```

if i don't send any arguments it works fine, however when i do send any argument i get `exit status 2`, and inside `stderr` i get `python: can't open file 'x': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` (if i send a single argument `x`).  i understand that this happens because when there are arguments, the `exec.Command` behaves as if the first one is the python script that should be executed.

one way of overcoming this should be extracting the script file's path (and not its content, which is what `argsTestScript` var holds).  i tried doing so by setting this var to be of type `embed.FS` instead of string, but i could only find a way to extract the file name, not its full path.

is there any way to achieve this?  either trick the `exec.Command` to receive the arguments after the script file, or extract the script file path?  or any other option?

cheers,
eRez

Comment: `exit status 2` is the exit status, which is usually accompanied by some error output. Look at the output for clues as to why the command failed.

Comment: @JimB when i send single argument `x` the error output is `python: can't open file 'x': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, which - as i wrote yesterday - indicates that `exec.Command` expects there a script file and not an argument

Comment: You're passing your `args` as the first argument to the python interpreter, but the actual program is going to come from stdin. There's probably a way to explicitly tell `python` that the program will be via stdin, and to not look for a file to execute.

Comment: i've found a workaround - to make a temp copy of the script file, extract its path, and send it as the second argument to the python interpreter, followed by the actual agrs

Comment: Looking at the [`python -h`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) output, it says to use `-` as the argument to indicate stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @JimB mentioned above - when using stdin and sending arguments to the python method - the first argument should simply be `-`

```
args:= []string{"-", "x", "y", "z"}
```

however make sure your python method ignores this hyphen, as the output of my go script will be -

```
output =  Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['-', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```